# Simple code will not compile with clang or gcc but it will with g++

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, clang

Why does my cpp code fail when I try to build it with gcc or clang but not g++?
With gcc or clang I get undefined reference errors, but no errors with g++

This is my simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
      cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
      return 0;
}
```

➜ clang main.cpp
/bin/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-ld: /tmp/main-986467.o: in function `main': main.cpp:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to` std::cout'

➜ gcc main.cpp -o myProg
/bin/ld: /tmp/ccJjbZYp.o: warning: relocation against `_ZSt4cout' in read-only section` .text' /bin/ld: /tmp/ccJjbZYp.o: in function `main': main.cpp:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to` std::cout'

Answer (score 1):

The code *compiles* with `gcc` and `clang` - but since they are usually used to compile `C` programs, they do not link with the C++ standard library by default - so the ***linking*** phase fails.

You can link with a C++ standard library to confirm this.

Examples:

```
gcc main.cpp -lstdc++

clang main.cpp -stdlib=libc++ -lc++
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it makes sense now. i figured the file extension, and or the contents of the filew would lead gcc or clang to figure out that it was c++ code they were dealing with, but obviously not....

Comment: @eamoc You're welcome, and yes, as you've noticed, a file ending with `.cpp` will not make `gcc` or `clang` add the necessary libaries.